# MongoDB (Mongoose), letter case issue in a connection string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example I'm using mongoose with a following connection string `my_lovely_db`, if database with such connection string doesn't exist it will be created upon first connection attempt. Once I accidentally changed connection string to `My_lovely_db`. Nothing happened, exception wasn't thrown, new database wasn't created, objects in my collection which exists in `my_lovely_db` weren't found. It took our team a while to understand what did happen. 
I checked [Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) tutorial, but except mentioning that connection string is case sensitive, nothing said about my use case.

In a near feature we will implement something like `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase` in a code, so this won't happen again, but right now I'd like to know what did happen here? Why database wasn't created and exception wasn't thrown? We can't immediately change all our databases connection string, so we need some indication that something went wrong. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: What connection events are you listening to?

Comment: I'm using `mongoose.connect` which returns promise, if promise resolved it means that connection successful and I init other applications parts.